# Blazor 8 SSR: Model Binding Complex objects with List

Tags: .net, forms, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I can not get a Blazor EditForm with complex objects to work.

Here's an example of a simple Dice Roller, where the user can select the amount of dices and dice types he wants to roll. When Submitting the form, the formData variable is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@using DiceMaster.Lib.Dices
@using System.ComponentModel
<EditForm Enhance Model="@formData" OnValidSubmit="@RollDices" FormName="DiceRoller">
   
    @foreach (var am in formData.Amounts)
    {
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="am.DiceTypeId">
            @foreach (DiceType ty in diceTypeGetter.GetDiceTypes())
            {
                <option value="@ty.TypeId">@ty.Name</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="am.DiceCount" min="1" max="1000000"></InputNumber>
    }


    <button type="submit">Roll</button>
</EditForm>

@if (rollResults.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DiceRollResult result in rollResults.OrderBy(r=>r.DiceTypeId).ThenBy(r=>r.SortIndex))
    {
        <div>@result.Value</div>
    }
}

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public RoleDiceFormInfo formData { get; set; }

    private DiceTypeGetter diceTypeGetter { get; set; } = new DiceTypeGetter();
    private List<DiceRollResult> rollResults { get; set; } = new List<DiceRollResult>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (formData is null)
        {
            formData = new() {Amounts = new List<DiceTypeAmmount>()
            {
                new DiceTypeAmmount()
                {
                    DiceCount = 1, DiceTypeId = diceTypeGetter.GetDiceTypes().First(d=>d.Name == "D6").TypeId
                },new DiceTypeAmmount()
                {
                    DiceCount = 1,DiceTypeId = diceTypeGetter.GetDiceTypes().First(d=>d.Name == "D3").TypeId
                }
            }};
        }
       
    }

    private void RollDices()
    {
        DiceRoller roller = new DiceRoller();
        DiceRollRequest request = new DiceRollRequest();
        request.DiceAmmounts = new List<DiceTypeAmmount>();
        request.DiceAmmounts.AddRange(formData.Amounts);
        List<DiceRollResult> results = roller.RollDices(request);
        rollResults = results;
    }

    public class RoleDiceFormInfo
    {
        public List<DiceTypeAmmount> Amounts { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class DiceTypeAmmount()
    {
        public Guid DiceTypeId { get; set; }
        public int DiceCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expect the formData model to bind correctly

Comment: SSR doesn't work for interactive https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-modes Try add `@rendermode InteractiveServer`

Comment: Yes, but ssr can handle traditional forms. That's what i am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the name of the select would be rendered as am.DiceTypeId:

[image]

However,in static ssr ,model binding would perform as MVC/RazorPage,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#collections) for more details

requires the name to be rendered as

```
formData.Amounts[index].DiceCount
```

I tried to modify the name attribute with InputSelect/InputNumber component ,but both failed whatever in for loop /foreach loop

If you would accept dropping `InputSelect/InputNumber` component,the codes below would work for you:

```
@{
    int index = 0;
}
@foreach (var am in formData.Amounts)
{


    <select name="formData.Amounts[@index].DiceTypeId" @bind="@formData.Amounts[@index].DiceTypeId">
        //I don't know the codes in your GetDiceTypes() method
        <option value="@Guid.NewGuid()">Type1</option>
        <option value="@Guid.NewGuid()">Type2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="formData.Amounts[@index].DiceCount" @bind="@formData.Amounts[@index].DiceCount" min="1" max="1000000">

     index++;
 
}
```

It would work on myside:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked!! Now i know I have to handle forms in blazor like in MVC :)